# How to tell if you are on a view page in preprocess_page

Tags: views, 8, theming

I am trying to see if we are on a view page in the preprocess_page function in my MYTHEME.theme file.

views_get_page_view() gives me an undefined function error.

I want to get values from my view to display outside the view area in page.html.twig

Answer (score 11):

That function will error because it does not exist in Drupal 8.

You can do this though:

```
$view_id = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('view_id');
$view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView($view_id);
```

Be sure to validate `view_id` first though, that it exists/length before calling the second line.